# Turn off anti aliasing on CCSprite (Cocos2D iPhone)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, antialiasing

When a CCSprite of mine, which uses a 16x16 image, is scaled up, there is a lot of blurring.

This image is pixel art, and therefore meant to be pixelated, but not blurred.

I've tried running the method `setAntiAliasTexParameters` on the texture of the sprite, but it doesn't change anything.

Here is the code: (mainSprite is CCSprite and slide1 is CCTexture2D)

```
slide1 = [[CCTexture2D alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"slide1.png"]];
[slide1 setAntiAliasTexParameters];

[mainSprite setTexture:slide1];
```

Thank you, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Use `setAliasTexParameters` instead of `setAntiAliasTexParameters`. That should turn off antialiasing for your chosen sprite.